# Maximo Anywhere remove HTML tag from long description

Tags: javascript, html, richtext, maximo, maximo-anywhere

I am trying to remove HTML tag from Work Execution long description field. These field was disabled for editing and after that I have enabled it. But the thing is that it has started to show HTML tag inside of the long description. It is very hard to understand what is the clear text of it.

I don't know howe to remove these tag from there and where to find the related js file for adding script.

If you have any idea about this issue, please let me know. I didn't add any picture about it but, if you need any document I try to get it as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Hi there I think it's a relatively easy fix - Change the widget from a `<textarea editable="true"` to `<text cssClass="richText" editable="true"`. 
That should render the styles appropriately.

Comment: Were you able to find a solution for this ? I tried `<text cssClass ="richText" editable="true"` however the HTML tags still appear in the long description